# Do we need an aphostrope when using "fan"?

Tags: possessives

The title is clear enough I guess, do we use an aphostrope, for instance fans of Mike, is it Mike's fans or Mike fans?

Comment: "Mike's fans" is correct, but so are "opera fans" and "Arsenal fans". "Arsenal's fans" is also correct. "Mike fans" and "opera's fans" both seem odd but not necessarily wrong? I am not sure how to pin down the difference.

Comment: "fan" as in "fanatic" or as in the thing that blows air when you are hot.

Comment: @JamesK fan as in fanatic. Sorry, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **apostrophe** indicates the possessive - fans 'belonging' to Mike.

> Mike's fans will be supporting him at the match tomorrow.

The person or thing people are fans of can also be treated as an attributive noun (one that acts like an adjective).

> I'm a Mike fan - I think he's brilliant.